# OR and GROUPBY operations on keys in nested dictonaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having a dictionary within a dictionary. And my problem statement is that I want to do an `or` operation on the keys (`'filter'` and `'filteer'`) 0 index in the dictionary. Based on that result I want to apply a `groupby` operation on the particular column in index 1 in the dictionary.
(for e.g if brand(conditions[0])== AMBI(conditions[8]) 
  (or) manufacturer(conditions[1])==AMBI(conditions[8]) i want to return dataframe and on that dataframe i want to perform groupby operation on one of the column.)

My code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys
class sample:
        def create_df(self, f):
                 self.z=pd.read_csv(f)
        def get_resultant_df(self, list_cols):
                 self.data_frame = self.z[list_cols[:]]
        def process_df(self, df, conditions):
                 resultant_df = self.data_frame   
                 if conditions[2] == 'equals':
                         new_df =resultant_df[resultant_df[conditions[1]] == conditions[3]]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'contains':
                         new_df = resultant_df[resultant_df[conditions[1]].str.contains(conditions[3])]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'not equals':
                         new_df = resultant_df[resultant_df[conditions[1]] != conditions[3]]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'startswith':
                         new_df = resultant_df[resultant_df[conditions[1]].str.startswith(conditions[3])]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'in':
                         new_df = resultant_df[resultant_df[conditions[1]].isin(resultant_df[conditions[3]])]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'not in':
                         new_df = resultant_df[~resultant_df[conditions[1]].isin(resultant_df[conditions[3]])]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'group':
                         new_df = list(resultant_df.groupby(conditions[0])[conditions[1]])
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'specific':
                         new_df = resultant_df.loc[resultant_df[conditions[0]] == conditions[8]]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2] == 'same':
                         new_df = resultant_df[(resultant_df[conditions[0]] == conditions[8]) & (resultant_df[conditions[1]] == conditions[8])]
                         return new_df
                 elif conditions[2]=='trail':
                         new_df={0:{'filter'{'filter1':resultant_df.loc[resultant_df[conditions[0]] == conditions[8]]},'filteer':{'filter1':resultant_df.loc[resultant_df[conditions[0]] == conditions[8]]}},
                                 1:{'group':{resultant_df.groupby(new_df[0][filter])}}}
                         return new_df


if __name__ =='__main__':
        sample = sample()

      sample.create_df("/home/purpletalk/GrammarandProductReviews.csv")
        df = sample.get_resultant_df(['brand', 'reviews.id','manufacturer','reviews.title','reviews.username','id','dateAdded','reviews.rating'])
        new_df = sample.process_df(df, ['brand','manufacturer','trail','Windex', 'size', 'equal',8,700,'AMBI'])
        print (new_df[1][group])
```

Can please somebody help me? The above code returns errors, and I want to know how an `or` operation can be performed.

Comment: You may want to add 'pandas' tag (guessing by the use of .loc() and data_frame). Note your process_df() function is not returning anything - and the code that calls it expects a return value. Please show an example data set (minimal possible) and the expected result, because from the description it is not possible to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: It does not help to post multiple comments asking for help. Instead, (a) please fix the error that I pointed out already (missing return value from process_df), (b) provide an example of the input data - and what you expect the result to be (also, as requested already).
Also, try to fix the indents in the posted code, so that it actually reads as a valid Python code that one can copy try out.